# How to get any element from an ajax responsetext (or any html text string) with jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

What method is best to use to find any element in a html text string ? With the find method you need to have a wrapped element to actually find that subelement. filter seems to give me object of size() 0 . Any other methods that can get any element from any parent tag (html,head,body)?

```
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/p1_page/style_sheets/p1.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/p1_page/scripts/s1.js" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="content_wrapper">

<table><tr><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td>ala</td></tr><tr><td></td><td><span id="button_wrapper"><span id="button_on" ><input type="hidden" name="" value="1" /></span></span></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td></tr></table></div>

</body>

</html>
```

That is the html response (i had to delete the elements readable contents).

```
Tryed $(response).find('body') returns object with size() 0;  
Tryed $(response).filter('body') returns object of size() 0;  
Tryed $('body', response) returns object of size() 0;  
But $(response) returns an object os size() 7; I don't get it
```

Comment: could you clarify a little bit more?, if you could use an example it would be better,

Comment: @FaddelHomsi How do i get the body and head of a html string (full html doc)?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of

```
var html = $(htmlString);
```

And then you take:

```
var body = html.find("body");
```

Comment: How would you do that to find/filter body and head elements contents?

Comment: That doesnt work...have u tested it?thats why i asked this...filter and find doesnt seem to get the body or head of a html string

Comment: And again have u tested it on a full html page ? it doesnt seem to work for me... jquery 171

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    var htmlStr='<html><head><title>My Title X</title></head><body><div class="NewDiv">Data in the DIV in html string</div></body></html>';
    $htmlStr=$(htmlStr);
    console.log($htmlStr.find('title').text());//null
    console.log($htmlStr.closest('title').text());//My Title X
    console.log($htmlStr.find('div').hasClass('NewDiv'));//prints false
    console.log($htmlStr.closest('div').hasClass('NewDiv'));//prints true});
```

jquery closest returns the expected elements when selecting elements other than "head".

You can try parsing the content as XML , with Jquery 1.5+
like

```
var xmlObj=$.parseXML(htmlStr);
    console.log($.parseXML(htmlStr).getElementsByTagName('head'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var htmlObj = $(string);
```

Then,

```
htmObj.find();
```

OR

```
htmlObj.filter(); etc..
```

For example:

To get `html` tag contents:

```
htmlObj.find('html').something()..  
//Or
$('html', htmlObj).something()....
```

To get `head` tag contents:

```
htmlObj.find('head').something()..  
//Or
$('head', htmlObj).something()....
```

To get `body` tag contents:

```
htmlObj.find('body').something()..  
//Or
$('body', htmlObj).something()....
```

AND SO ON....

Comment: How would you do that to find/filter body and head elements contents?

Comment: I'm on jquery 171 and any of does doesnt seem to work for me...t hats why i asked this